# Not able to understand the output of this javascript code

Tags: javascript

Why does the following code print `undefined`? Also after removing the `if` block it prints `hello there` as output.

```
var message = "hello there!";

function hello(){
  console.log(message);

  if (true) {
    var message = "wassup?!";
  }
}

hello();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's called *hoisting*. From [the Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) (emphasis added):

> Variable declarations, **wherever they occur**, are processed before any code is executed. The scope of a variable declared with `var` is its current *execution context*, which is either the enclosing function or, for variables declared outside any function, global.

The `var message` declared inside the `if` block hides the global `message` variable for all the code inside the function, including the call to `console.log()`.

Two additional points. First, JavaScript separates variable declaration from variable initialization. That's why the local `message` variable has an undefined value when `console.log(message)` executes, rather than `"wassup?!"`. Second, because hoisting is such counter-intuitive behavior (at least for programmers used to other languages), most JavaScript linting tools will warn you about `var` statements that are not at the start of their execution context. I strongly recommend that you find a linting tool (JSLint, JSHint, ESLint and JSCS come to mind) and use it.

Answer (score 1):

It happens when you define a local variable with the same name as a global. Since there is a `var message` in the scope of the function, it will only refer to the local `message` rather than the global one. Since it wasn't given a value at that time it's `undefined`. Notice if you move it to after the `if` it will be `"wassup?!"`.

The solution is you probally didn't want to make a local variable. So change `var message = "wassup?!"` to `message = "wassup?!"`.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Spencer Wieczorek's answer, variable definition is 'hoisted' to the top of it's scope, while variable assignment remains at the location you write it. So the code you have provided actually translates like this:

```
var message = "hello there!";

function hello(){
  var message;
  console.log(message);

  if (true) {
    message = "wassup?!";
  }
}

hello();
```

Which explains a little more clearly why you see these results - BEFORE your `console.log()` call, the `message` variable is created in the scope of the `hello()` function, but it doesn't get the value `'wassup?!'` until later in the function.

EDIT: [Here's a bit more info on this behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), which, as @TedHopps points out in comments, is called hoisted, not 'hitched'.

Comment: +1, but I believe that the standard term for this behavior is [_hoisted_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), not "hitched". :)

Comment: @TedHopp You're absolutely right. You know I sat here staring at it yesterday sure that it didn't look right but unable to put my finger on what it was. Editing it in now, Thanks!